# AngularJs Textarea with HTML preview in a DIV, why I go "bindings.push is not a function" and how to catch errors while writing HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs

Hello I'm trying to build a HTML previewer: while editing HTML source in a textarea I want it to be previewd inside a container div:

Everything is working exept that in the browser console i get the following two type of errors:

1. TypeError: bindings.push is not a function
2. While writing new code in the text area I get a html validation error, I believe it comes from the ngSanitize module

How can I fix the first problem?
How can I catch the second error and display it out to the interface in order to alert the Editor?

Thanks for help.

This is made under a blade view (LRVL5), here's the code:

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<script>
    var bindings = new Array();
    'use strict';
    angular.module('htmlEditor', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('HTMLController', function() {
        this.html = '{!! preg_replace("/\'/", "\\'", $html) !!}';  
      });
</script>


<div  ng-app="htmlEditor" ng-controller="HTMLController as htmlctrl">
<div  class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Edit</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Preview</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="elementId">Id</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="elementId" value="{{$id}}" >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="elementName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="elementName" value="{{$name}}">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="elementHTML">HTML Body</label>
                <textarea  ng-model="htmlctrl.html" rows="20" class="form-control" id="elementHTML" placeholder="Email Html source for Body">{{$html}}</textarea>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <form>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="jumbotron" ng-bind-html="htmlctrl.html" >

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Where are you calling bindings.push? If another component/module is using that variable then I highly doubt it's meant to be a defined as a global.

Comment: not calling it. I believe it's automatically called by setting ng-bind-html="htmlctrl.html" (see last layer)

Comment: Ok surely it should be declared be in the controller then

Comment: not a solution. Even placing a this.bindings=new Array(); in the controller closure, it's not goin to work.

Comment: Not offering a solution. Hence why I didn't provide an answer. Only suggestions. But now I look at it again. The wording angular textbox threw me, it's a standard textbox  your trying to bind. I'll post an answer shortly.